# IS keyword C# - to which assemby does it belong - where is it defined?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been looking into .NET assemblies using ILSpy. I would like to know where is "IS" (and "AS") keyword defined so I can take a look at its definition, to see how "IS" operator is defined inside .NET.
Thank you

Comment: You will not find a 'definition' of a keyword there.. You can only find what operations that keyword causes..

Comment: They are language constructs handled by the compiler and won't feature as a type definition anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are defined in the [language specification for C#](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) and implemented in the compiler, no particular assembly. Although the functionality needed to make it work at runtime should be in <strike>mscorlib</strike> the Just In Time Compiler.

If you red the standard for C# 4 at ECMA (linked above) you will find the the `is operator` in the section 14.9.10 and `as operator` in the section 14.9.11.

When compiled the is operator becomes the `Isinst` instruction:

```
public bool IsDateTime(object o)
{
    return o is DateTime;
}
```

becomes:

```
.method public hidebysig instance bool IsDateTime(object o) cil managed
{
  .maxstack  8
  ldarg.1
  isinst     [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  ldnull
  cgt.un
  ret
}
```

The `as operator` may also be compiled to the Isinst instruction:

```
public String AsString(object o)
{
    return o as String;
}
```

becomes:

```
.method public hidebysig instance string AsString(object o) cil managed
{
    .maxstack  8
    ldarg.1     
    isinst     [mscorlib]System.String
    ret
}
```

These instructions are defined in the [Common Language Infraestructure specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), Isinst is defined in the section III.4.6.

Comment: What do you mean `the functionality needed to make it work at runtime should be in mscorlib`? It's not like `is` gets translated into a method call or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Keywords are part of the language, not the API.

Comment: But someone has to define the operator, is there a language specification anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you can find the PDFs i.e. on MSDN.

Comment: @AntunTun, here you have http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Both `is` and `as` are translated directly into CIL instruction [`Isinst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx).
And cast operator is translated into [`Castclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.castclass.aspx).

You can learn a bit more about these instructions from the [CLI speficication](https://www4.cs.fau.de/Lehre/WS05/V_MW/Uebung/doc/CLI_Ecma-335-part-i-iv.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

`is` and `as` are language elements, like `for`, `while`, `switch`, `foreach` and such. They're not defined in any assembly.